# Can ♂ (male symbol) be printed from charset ISO-8859-1?

Tags: unicode, ascii, iso-8859-1

When I searched online I saw that ASCII code 11 equals to Vertical Tab or the male symbol, but I could not actually output the male symbol to a File by using ISO-8859-1. It just displayed as a question mark('?')

When 'UTF-8' was used it displayed nicely. The unicode for the male symbol is U+2642. So is it not in the range supported by ISO-8859-1?

Comment: [Based on the list of characters shown on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), it doesn't look like ISO-8859-1 contains a "♂" symbol.

Comment: If you want to communicate using a standard set of globally accepted symbols, use UTF8, rather than something that will be interpreted differently depending on the 7bit character set the recipient likes to see

Comment: The ASCII table you used came from the 1980s.  Code 11 is ♂ in the olden IBM PC character ROM.  Carried forward only in the OEM character sets like 437.  With no practical way to tell the reader of the file what character set you used, 8859 too belongs on the scrapheap of historical bad ideas.  The world speaks Unicode today.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, this bit of history solves my problem.

Comment: It's actually the arbitrary text file and text file formats that don't have standardized rules about character encodings (e.g., CSV)  that are the problem.  Such files are for experts that want to deal with keeping track of which character encoding was used on each file they possess or communicate. There are many better choices for text content in files.

Answer (score 2):

> The unicode for the male symbol is U+2642. So is it not in the range supported by ISO-8859-1?

[No, it is not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). These are the only characters defined in ISO-8859-1:

[image]